# installing firefox for OpenShift DIY cartridge

Tags: firefox, openshift

I need to scrap websites with python (selenium) so i need to install Firefox or chrome or ... .

with openshift servers how could i install Firefox in an OpenShift DIY cartridge?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I take it you did not like my phantoms and Casperjs answer in your other question? ;)

Comment: Thanks , but i not familiar to java Lang and phantoms and casperjs are in java so, i prefer to work with selenium in python. so i need to install Firefox for it.

Comment: They are both JavaScript based not Java. There are plenty of real simple examples on how to get the webpage you want and do all your scraping in Python. That's how I did it at first.

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25910106/pyhton-selenium-in-openshift-server

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no xwindows system installed on OpenShift, I dont' think that firefox will be able to either 1.) be installed or 2.) run on the platform.

You would be better off using something like the nokogiri gem with Ruby, or a python/php library for scraping web content.  You might also consider doing the scraping on your own computer, then upload the information that is needed by your website if you HAVE to go the firefox/chrome route.

Answer (score 0):

There are instructions for running Selenium tests in Firefox on a headless server on the OpenShift blog.

https://blog.openshift.com/selenium-ruby-jenkins/